# Android: fastScrollEnabled not working at first

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

OK, I am working on an App that has a page with a listview and a edittext box at top.  As you type things into the edittext box it will filter what items are shown in the listview.  The problem I am having is with the fast scroll icon that appears on the side of the slider.
When the page first loads NO MATTER what I do the fast scroll slider icon will not appear on the screen. Then I click in the edit text box and type one character and then erase it and now my fast scroll slider icon will appear.

First load no fast scroll icon.
[image: no fast scroll icon]

Edittext box and then erase text and fast scroll icon appears.
[image: fast scroll appears]

I have the android:fastScrollEnabled="true" set in my listview.  Plus I have set it manually in the code by doing lv1.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

No matter I change I still get the same behavior, unless I remove it complete from the code and xml and then it will stop working on the second page.  I have tried cleaning my project and still no good.  I am leaning towards it being a bug in android or I am missing something extremely simple.

Here is my code.

```
public class SearchByFood extends ParentClass
{
private ListView lv1;
private EditText ed;
int textlength = 0;
private ArrayList<String> arr_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<Food> foodList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_by_food);
    setTextTitle("Search by Food");

    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    DataLayerFunctions d = new DataLayerFunctions(getApplicationContext());

    foodList = d.selectFoodsWithSubstitutes();
    for (Food f : foodList)
    {
        // this is to build a ArrayList<String> to pass to the setAdapter
        Log.d("SearchByFood", "FoodName: " + f.getFood_Name());
        foods.add(f.getFood_Name());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> firstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchByFood.this, R.layout.search_food_listview, foods);
    lv1.setAdapter(firstAdapter);
    lv1.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            textlength = ed.getText().length();
            arr_sort.clear();
            for (String f : foods)
            {
                if (textlength <= f.length())
                {
                    if (f.toString().toLowerCase().contains((CharSequence) ed.getText().toString().toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        Log.d("STRING", "STRING: " + f.toString() + " contains " + ed.getText());

                        if (ed.getText().length() > 0)
                        {
                            String newString = boldMyString(f, ed.getText().toString());
                            arr_sort.add(newString);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            arr_sort.add(f);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            // if empty add a no foods found
            if (arr_sort.isEmpty())
            {
                arr_sort.add("No Foods Found");
            }

            // Load array
            // lv1.setAdapter(new
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchByFood.this, R.layout.search_food_listview, arr_sort)
            {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                {
                    View row;

                    if (null == convertView)
                    {
                        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_food_listview, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row = convertView;
                    }

                    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getItem(position)));
                    // tv.setText(getItem(position));

                    return row;
                }

            };
            lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        private String boldMyString(String foodName, String guess)
        {
            int gLength = guess.length();
            ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int i = foodName.toLowerCase().indexOf(guess.toLowerCase()); i >= 0; i = foodName.toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(guess.toLowerCase(), i + 1))
            {
                System.out.println("TEST:" + i);
                results.add(i);
            }

            // Count value is for words that have 2 or more values of guess
            // in them.
            int count = 0;
            for (int i : results)
            {
                StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer(foodName);
                s1.insert(i + count, "<b>");
                count = count + 3;

                s1.insert(i + count + gLength, "</b>");
                count = count + 4;

                foodName = s1.toString();
                System.out.println("FOOD NAME:" + i + ":" + foodName);

            }
            return foodName;
        }
    });

    // This is what actually does stuff when you click on a listview item.
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            // Strip out the bold tags
            String clicked = (String) lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            clicked = clicked.replaceAll("<b>", "");
            System.out.println("Clicked" + clicked);
            clicked = clicked.replaceAll("</b>", "");

            // Find the Food ID match and pass the food id to the
            // fooddisplay page
            for (Food f : foodList)
            {
                if (null != clicked && clicked.equals(f.getFood_Name()))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchByFood.this, SubstituteDisplay.class);
                    intent.putExtra("FoodID", f.getFood_ID());
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MasterTemplateActivity.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    return;
}
}
```

Again, any help as to why my fast scroll icon doesn't show up at first would be much appreciated.  It is a small thing but it is really annoying me.

Comment: try having the fastScrollEnabled=true in the xml. removed it from the code. may be that will work. i've similar problems with fastscroll..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try `list.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true)`

and also try `list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);` so that icon appears when scroll is called...

something like this..

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run(){
    list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: OK, I was using my app today showing it to a friend and I synced with my online database.  My wife had added about 10 more things to the list and after I synced with the online DB all the sudden (without any code changes) it just started working all the time. 

I am not sure why that resolved it, but it did.  Although, i got to give you props.  This worked as well.  Just fix it to be new Handler().po.....  Thanks again.

Comment: @S.A.Jay .. may be because preveously you had list count less than 35.. fast scroll bar appears only if list count is above 35...

Comment: I hadn't heard that before, but it makes sense.  I did have less than 35 and then more than 35.  The problem I have with that is that as you can see from the second screenshot I had the fast scroll icon appear after typing in characters and then erasing them before I had 35 in the list.

Comment: @ngesh Whether fast scroll is available or not depends on the ListView's actual height on the device, not on a general item count, does it? ;)

Comment: 2019, and @ngesh comment still valid. Thanks a ton! I was wondering why it was not working but it actually depends on count.

Answer (score 0):

So again I'm posting this because my issue was genuinly different. Fast scrolling also doesn't seem to work in a `ConstraintLayout`. Both `ListView` Fast Scrolling and `RecyclerView` Fast Scrolling don't seem to work.