# setFastScrollEnabled don't work perfectly

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an App that has a page with a listview and a edittext box at top. As you type things into the edittext box it will filter what items are shown in the listview. The problem I am having is with the fast scroll icon that appears on the side of the slider.
The scroller go out the view when i type the letter "b for example.

[image]

I have added this lines (to refresh my list scroller) and it didn't work.

```
_filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);

_filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        _listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);

        _listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

    }
```

i have also se this subject and follow it, and i guess it wasn't the same problem.
[Android: fastScrollEnabled not working at first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255624/android-fastscrollenabled-not-working-at-first)

Ok, here is all my class:

```
public class StationsFragment extends GoogleAnalyticsFragment implements Observer{

    private Boolean mDebug = true;

    private ListView            _listView;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );

        activity = (FragmentsActivity) getActivity();

        mStationsViewContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stations_activity, null);

        _listView = (ListView)  mStationsViewContainer.findViewById( R.id.stations_listView );

            activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

            _stationsAdapter = new StationsAdapter();

            _listView.setAdapter(_stationsAdapter);

            _listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

            _listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

            _listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);

            registerForContextMenu(_listView);

            _listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                }
            });

            _stationsList.addObserver(this);

            _filterText = (EditText) mStationsViewContainer.findViewById( R.id.search_box );

            TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    _listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);

                    _listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    _filterMode = _filterText.getText().length() > 0;

                    _stationsAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }
            };

            _filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

            _stationsAdapter.getFilter().filter("");

        }

        return mStationsViewContainer;
    }

class StationsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer, Filterable {

        HashMap<String, Integer>    _alphaIndexer;

        public ArrayList<Station>   _filtered   = new ArrayList<Station>();

        String[]                    _sections;

        MyFilter                    _filter;

        public StationsAdapter() {

            super();

            _filter = new MyFilter();
        }

        public void updateIndex() {

            _alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            for (int x = 0; x < _filtered.size(); x++) {

                Station s = (Station) _filtered.get(x);

                // get the first letter of the store
                String ch = s.getTitle().substring(0, 1);

                // convert to uppercase otherwise lowercase a -z will be sorted
                // after upper A-Z
                ch = ch.toUpperCase();

                if (!_alphaIndexer.containsKey(ch)) {

                    if (_filterMode) {

                        _alphaIndexer.put(ch, x);

                    } else {

                        _alphaIndexer.put(ch, x + _favouriteManager.getFavourites().length);
                    }
                }
            }

            Set<String> sectionLetters = _alphaIndexer.keySet();

            ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);

            Collections.sort(sectionList);

            if (!_filterMode && _favouriteManager.getFavourites().length > 0) {

                sectionList.add(0, "\u2605");
            }

            _sections = new String[sectionList.size()];

            sectionList.toArray(_sections);

            if (!_filterMode && _favouriteManager.getFavourites().length > 0) {

                _alphaIndexer.put("\u2605", 0);
            }
        }

        public int getCount() {

            if (_filterMode) {

                if (mDebug) Log.i("StationFragment","filter size ="+_filtered.size());

                return _filtered.size();

            } else {

                return _filtered.size() + _favouriteManager.getFavourites().length;
            }

        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {

            if (_filterMode) {

                return _filtered.get(position);

            } else {

                if (position < _favouriteManager.getFavourites().length) {

                    return _favouriteManager.getFavourites()[position];

                } else {

                    return _filtered.get(position - _favouriteManager.getFavourites().length);
                }
            }
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (mDebug)     Log.i("ks3","getView called, position is " + position);

            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stations_cell_custom, null);
            }

            if (!_filterMode) {

                if (position < _favouriteManager.getFavourites().length) {

                    Favourite favourite = _favouriteManager.getFavourites()[position];

                    Station station = _stationsList.findStationById(favourite.getFavouriteId());

                    TextView details = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.details));

                    if (_pushedFromRoutes || _pushedFromWidgetConfiguration) {

                        details.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else {

                        details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    TextView name = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name));

                    if (station != null) {

                        name.setText(station.getName());

                        //name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.stations_list_favourite_text_color));

                    } else {

                        name.setText("");
                    }

                    details.setText(favourite.getUserSettings().formattedDateTime());

                    TextView header = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_textview));

                    View headerBar = ((View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_bar));

                    if (position == 0) {

                        header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        headerBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        header.setText(getString(R.string.star_favourites));

                    } else {

                        header.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        headerBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        header.setText(null);
                    }

                } else {

                    Station station = _filtered.get(position - _favouriteManager.getFavourites().length);

                    TextView name = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name));

                    name.setText(station.getName());

                    name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.stations_list_text_color));

                    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.details)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    TextView header = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_textview));

                    View headerBar = ((View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_bar));

                    String firstLetter = station.getTitle().substring(0, 1);

                    /*if (position == _alphaIndexer.get(firstLetter)) {

                        TextView header = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.header_textview);

                        header.setText(firstLetter);
                    }*/


                    if (position == _alphaIndexer.get(firstLetter)) {

                        header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        headerBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        header.setText(firstLetter);

                    } else {

                        header.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        headerBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        header.setText(null);
                    }
                }

            } else {

                Station station = _filtered.get(position);

                TextView name = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name));

                name.setText(station.getName());

                name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.stations_list_text_color));

                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.details)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                TextView header = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_textview));

                View headerBar = ((View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_bar));

                String firstLetter = station.getTitle().substring(0, 1);

                if (position == _alphaIndexer.get(firstLetter)) {

                    header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    headerBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    header.setText(firstLetter);

                } else {

                    header.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    headerBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    header.setText(null);
                }
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        public int getPositionForSection(int section) {

            return _alphaIndexer.get(_sections[section]);
        }

        public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {

            return 0;
        }

        public Object[] getSections() {

            return _sections;
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {

            return _filter;
        }

        class MyFilter extends Filter {

            @Override

            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {

                if (resultValue != null) {

                    Station station = (Station) resultValue;

                    if (station != null) {

                        return station.getTitle();
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override

            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                String pattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

                ArrayList<Station> filt = new ArrayList<Station>();

                if (_pushedFromRoutes || _pushedFromWidgetConfiguration) {

                    synchronized (_stationsList.stations()) {

                        for (int i = 0, l = _stationsList.stations().length; i < l; i++) {

                            Station s = _stationsList.stations()[i];

                            if (pattern == null || pattern.length() == 0 || s.match(pattern))

                                filt.add(s);
                        }

                        result.count = filt.size();

                        result.values = filt;
                    }

                } else {

                    synchronized (_stationsList.belgianStations()) {

                        for (int i = 0, l = _stationsList.belgianStations().length; i < l; i++) {

                            Station s = _stationsList.belgianStations()[i];

                            if (pattern == null || pattern.length() == 0 || s.match(pattern))

                                filt.add(s);
                        }

                        result.count = filt.size();

                        result.values = filt;
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override

            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                _filtered = (ArrayList<Station>) results.values;

                updateIndex();

                _listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);

                notifyDataSetChanged();

                _listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

                if (mDebug) Log.i("StationFragment","list count ="+_listView.getCount());

                if (_filterMode && _filtered.size() == 0) {

                    _listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    _noResultsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {

                    _listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    _noResultsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

You see that i have to generate a complex list, i think that the problem may come from this, maybe scroller can get the max and the min? i really don't get it?

I tried my code in an activity (i thunked that maybe problem comes from fragment) and when i test it , it still don't work in my tablet Samsung Galaxy. i tried it in a Nexus S and it worked. The problem i must use this code in a fragment and it must work in the tablet especially GalaxyTab.

Comment: This often happens when the code to update or filter the list is done in such a way the the `FastScroller` object does not get notified.  Can you post the code snippets where you update your `ListAdapter` based on data set changes and/or text input filtration?

Comment: i have added my listAdapter, please check it.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, the issue is that your `SectionIndexer` implementation is unbalanced.  Currently you have:

```
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {

        return _alphaIndexer.get(_sections[section]);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {

        return _sections;
    }
```

There is a workable implementation telling the list how to determine the position of where a given section begins in `getPositionForSection()`, but nothing about how to determine which section a given position is located in `getSectionForPosition()`.

When I run a simplified example (on my GTab 10.1 with Android 3.1) using this indexer code I can easily get the scroller handle to go completely off-screen so a user can't get it at all without scrolling all the way to the top of the list.  The way to fix this is to balance the indexer by implementing the other method properly:

```
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {

        return _alphaIndexer.get(_sections[section]);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        //Iterate over the sections to find the closest index
        //that is not greater than the position
        int closestIndex = 0;
        int latestDelta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(int i=0; i < _sections.length; i++) {
            int current = _alphaIndexer.get(_sections[i]);
            if(current == position) {
                //If position matches an index, return it immediately
                return i;
            } else if(current < position) {
                //Check if this is closer than the last index we inspected
                int delta = position - current;
                if(delta < latestDelta) {
                    closestIndex = i;
                    latestDelta = delta;
                }
            }
        }

        return closestIndex;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {

        return _sections;
    }
```

In my example anyway, fixing the `SectionIndexer` to be more balanced eliminates the issue and the scroll handle never goes below the view.  This example code may not work copy/paste for your data source, but it should give you an idea of how to put it into your code.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try these calls in `onTextChanged()` so that the first item gets selected after filtering.

```
listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

OR

```
listView.setSelection(0);
```