# Why is the fast scroll bar not showing in Lollipop

Tags: android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop, fastscroll

So I have a `ListView` and I'm trying to add the Fast Scroll bar to it like so:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
```

This works fine on API 19, but on API 21 or 22 it doesn't show up at all - on both emulators and devices.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Strange, it works just fine for me

Comment: Same with me. Perhaps some styling issue?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255624/android-fastscrollenabled-not-working-at-first

Comment: Created an example project to test it out and it works fine.... so there must by something else affecting it - appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Is your adapter implementing [SectionIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html)?

```
package android.widget;

public interface SectionIndexer {
    Object[] getSections();

    int getPositionForSection(int var1);

    int getSectionForPosition(int var1);
}
```